# wiring ceiling fan

Tags: ceiling-fan

Our house was wired for ceiling fans but they were never installed.

I recently put in the fans and they work well, but the pre-installed switch only turns the light off and on. The fan only works on pull chain.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved?

Comment: I assume your "preinstalled" switch is a wall switch, right? Is there only one switch on the wall that has wires to the ceiling box for the fan/light?  If the wiring in the wall switch box has both a neutral, you could install a second wall switch next to the original one. Does the cable in the wall switch box have a black, a red, a white and a ground?

Comment: This is an acceptable wiring for fan/light combos.  I've got one wired with both fan/light to the switch, which means I've still got to pull the light chain when I want fan on/Light off.  I prefer power to the fan all the time, and the light on the switch.

Answer (score 1):

If there are only 3 wires going to that fan box, presumably from the wall switch ( a "Romex" with black / white & bare ground) then you'll be out of options trying to hard wire a separate fan and light control.

However, both Lowe's and Home Depot as well as other optional places to purchase fans *DO* sell fans with really nice remotes of which can go in a little "holster" if you will mounted anywhere you like within proximity of your ceiling fan. Doing it this way, you would remove that switch and wire the fan "hot" and the fan's controls ( variable speed / reverse & lighting) are all taken care of for you.

Comment: If there is only one cable, there must surely be a /3 if the fan is able to run via pull chain with the light off.